# Partial derivative of a function of a matrix

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have this function of a matrix and two vectors:

$$f(x, V, y) = x^T V y$$ where $$V \in R^{d \times d}, x \in R^{d}, y \in R^{d}$$

Basically I need to optimize (find the minimum) of this function with respect to $V$, $x$, $y$. So $V$ here is a matrix of parameters, as well as $x$ and $y$ are vectors of parameters. The basic way to minimize this function is to compute the partial derivative of the function with respect to each parameter and then just use gradient descent or something. I've never computed the partial derivative of a function with respect to a matrix before so I just need someone to clarify that I'm doing this correctly.

My approach:

- $1$st step convert the matrix multiplication into summation format, so:

  $$f(x, V, y) = \sum_{i}^{d}x_{i} \sum_{j}^{d}V_{i,j} y_{j}$$
- Compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $V_{i,j}$:

  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial V_{i,j}} = \sum_{i}^{d}x_{i} \sum_{j}^{d} y_{j}$$
- Compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_{i}$

  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} = \sum_{i}^{d} \sum_{j}^{d}V_{i,j} y_{j}$$ and in a vectorized version this would be: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \hat x} = V y$
- Compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y_{j}$:

  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{j}} = \sum_{i}^{d}x_{i} \sum_{j}^{d}V_{i,j}$$

My questions:

- Are my calculations correct?
- Is it possible to convert the calculations of the partial derivatives into a vectorized format so I can calculate the partial derivatives of all the $V$ parameters in one shot? I need that because I need a fast computation!

Comment: The function does not have a finite minimum. Take $V=\mathrm{I}_{d}$ (the identity matrix) and $\displaystyle x = \begin{bmatrix} n \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y=-x$. Then,

$$ f(x,V,y) = x^{\top}Vy = -n^{2} $$

Comment: @jibounet i just need to see if my calculations are correct and if I can get a vectorized versions of the partial derivatives

Answer (score 2):

Let $f \, : \, \mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathcal{M}_{d}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ such that :

$$ f(x,V,y) = x^{\top}Vy $$

$\nabla_{x}f$ (resp. $\nabla_{V}f$, resp. $\nabla_{y}f$) denote the gradient of $f$ with respect to the variable $x$ (resp. $V$, resp. $y$), in other words, the gradient of the linear map $x \, \longmapsto \, f(x,V,y)$ (resp. $V \, \longmapsto \, f(x,V,y)$, resp. $y \, \longmapsto \, f(x,V,y)$). We have :

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\nabla_{x}f \, (x,V,y) = Vy \\[2mm]
\nabla_{V}f \, (x,V,y) = xy^{\top} \\[2mm]
\nabla_{y}f \, (x,V,y) = V^{\top}x \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

---

-- Update :

Let $(E,\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle)$ be an euclidean space of dimension $n$. Let $f \, : \, E \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ and a point $x \in E$. Let $\mathcal{L}(E,\mathbb{R})$ the space of [continuous] linear forms on $E$. By definition, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if there exist a linear form $ \in \mathcal{L}(E,\mathbb{R})$ such that :

$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + L(h) + \mathop{o} \limits_{\Vert h \Vert \to 0}\big( \Vert h \Vert \big)$$

$L$ is unique and I will use the notation : $L=\mathrm{D}_{x}f$ ( $\mathrm{D}_{x}f$ is the *differential of $f$ at $x$*) and $L(h) = \mathrm{D}_{x}f \cdot h$. Since $\mathrm{D}_{x}f$ is in $\mathcal{L}(E,\mathbb{R})$, [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) ensures that there exist a *unique* $x_{f} \in E$ such that : $\forall h, \, \mathrm{D}_{x}f \cdot h = \left\langle h,x_{f} \right\rangle$ (one could say that the linear form $\mathrm{D}_{x}f$ is "represented" by the vector $x_{f}$ throught the inner product $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$). Since $x_{f}$ is unique, we say that the vector $x_{f}$ is *the gradient of $f$ at $x$* and we write usually $x_{f} = \nabla f(x)$.

If $E = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ is the usual inner product, then : $\mathrm{D}_{x}f \cdot h = \left\langle h,\nabla f (x) \right\rangle = h^{\top} \nabla f (x)$.

If $E = \mathcal{M}_{d}(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of real square matrices of size $d$) and $\left\langle A,B \right\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A^{\top}B)$, then : $D_{x}f \cdot h = \left\langle h,\nabla f(x) \right\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(h^{\top} \nabla f(x))$. (Note that in this case, $\nabla f(x)$ is a matrix, since it is an element of $E$).

---

So, how could we proceed in order to get the gradient of $\varphi \, : \, x \, \longmapsto \, x^{\top}Vy$ ($V$ and $y$ are fixed here) ? Write :

$$ 
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x+h) &= {} \big( x+h \big)^{\top}Vy \\[2mm]
 &= x^{\top}Vy + h^{\top}Vy \\
\end{align*}
$$

In $\varphi(x+h)$, identify the $\varphi(x)$ part and the part which is linear in $h$, the differential of $\varphi$ at $x$ :

$$ \varphi(x+h) = \underbrace{x^{\top}Vy}_{\varphi(x)} + \underbrace{\color{red}{h^{\top}Vy}}_{\mathrm{D}_{x}\varphi \, \cdot \, h} $$

Now, we know that the differential and the gradient are linked by the relation : $\mathrm{D}_{x}\varphi \cdot h = h^{\top} \nabla \varphi (x)$ so we identify $h^{\top}Vy$ and $h^{\top} \nabla \varphi (x)$ :

$$ \nabla \varphi (x) = Vy $$

We can do the same for $\psi \, : \, V \, \longmapsto \, x^{\top}Vy$ :

$$
\begin{align*}
\psi(V+H) &= {} x^{\top}\big( V+H \big)y \\[3mm]
 &= \underbrace{x^{\top}Vy}_{\psi(V)} + \underbrace{\color{red}{x^{\top}Hy}}_{\mathrm{D}_{V} \psi \, \cdot \, H} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Here, $\mathrm{D}_{V}\psi \cdot H$ is not yet of the form $\mathrm{Tr}(H^{\top} \nabla \psi(V))$ so let's write :

$$
\begin{align*}
x^{\top}Hy &= {} \mathrm{Tr}\big( x^{\top}Hy \big) \\[2mm]
 &= \mathrm{Tr}\big( yx^{\top}H \big) \\[2mm]
 &= \mathrm{Tr}\big( H^{\top}xy^{\top} \big) \\
\end{align*}
$$

As a consequence :

$$ \nabla \psi(V) = xy^{\top}. $$

Comment: I think the last one can also be $x^T V$, right?

Comment: @AlexTwain : Usually, the gradient is a *column* vector, not a row vector. If you write $x^{\top}V$, it will be a row vector.

Comment: it took me a lot of time to reach the same calculations as yours. Is there some shortcuts/rules to do partial derivatives of functions that involves matrices and vectors? Because I had to transform the function into summation forms and think very *hardly* about it :(

Comment: @AlexTwain : I added explanations to my post. I hope it will be useful !

Comment: thanks a lot the edit was a bit useful, but unfortunately you assumed that I'm a linear algebra guru or something. I couldn't understand 70% of the theoretical stuff in the edit. What I mainly understood is that I should do $f(x+h)$ and make the forms as two forms. One for vectors and the other for matrices. Then I identify the gradient. I think you used too much notation and also I think you might have some mistakes which confused me.

Comment: would it be possible to edit it and make it more accessible and clearer? Like I didn't understand what the $o$ is for. If only you could make it less *mathy* or give it a better structure and organization for the explanation.

Comment: Would this one be simpler to understand https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4690685?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are incorrect because the free indices are not balanced across the equal sign! If an index appears on the RHS as a dummy (summed) index, it cannot appear on the LHS as a free (unsummed) index.

For example
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial V_{i,j}} &= x_{i} \, y_{j} 
    \,\neq\, \sum_{i}^{d}x_{i} \sum_{j}^{d} y_{j} \cr
}$$
To avoid simple mistakes like this, it is best to use the Einstein summation convention (that guy was *really* clever).

An index which appears only once is a free index. An index which appears twice is a dummy index. An index which appears 3 or more times is a *mistake*.

In that convention, 
these things are almost trivial to demonstrate, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
  f &= V_{i,j} \,\, x_{i} \, y_{j} \cr
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial V_{i,j}} &= x_{i} \, y_{j} \cr
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} &= V_{i,j} \,\, y_{j} \cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{j}} &= V_{i,j} \,\, x_{i} \cr
   &= x_{i}\,V_{i,j} \cr
}$$